# How can I connect to a HTTPS site via HTTP

Tags: ssl, https

We have CheckPoint in our company. I am using Anonymox to bypass CheckPoint. Everything is OK except when I try to connect HTTPS sites I cannot bypass CheckPoint.

For example I can watch videos on YouTube unless I'm logged into YouTube. If I log in, then YouTube starts to use HTTPS and I cannot connect.

Any solution for this?

Note: Anonymox is a plugin for Firefox that allows you to use their proxies.

Comment: Why would a regular proxy be able to bypass CheckPoint? Doesn’t make sense IMHO. The only way you can bypass it is by tunneling your connections, for example through SSH.

Comment: HTTPS is not like upgraded version of HTTP. HTTPS is an HTTP protocol running on top or inside an SSL tunnel. To connect to https site i think you need HTTPS or SOCKS proxy - not a pure HTTP one that is most probably provided by Anonymox. Check the list of https proxies in here: `http://proxylist.hidemyass.com/` and configure your browser to use one. This should be able to bypass the CheckPoint for https sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a web server is configured to redirect you to `https://example.com` from any `http://example.com` request, there is nothing you can do.

This is a server-side setting that you cannot influence. The server will not respond to HTTP.

If it was possible for someone to force the use of HTTP when the server only accepts HTTPS, this would constitute a huge security flaw.

Comment: I am afraid to hear that. Anyway. Thanks for your answer. Actually facebook , twitter and youtube is problem for me. I can bypass youtube by using it without login, but using others is still a problem...